# LightGBMError: b'Label must be in [0, 3), but found -2147483648 in label'

Tags: lightgbm

I was running cross validation using lightgbm and see the following error with one set of inputs while all my other inputs works well.

```
    LightGBMError: b'Label must be in [0, 3), but found -2147483648 in label'
```

All my inputs x, y are both numpy arrays and the following is my code for running cross validation:

```
    def cross_validate_lgbm():
        lgbm_params = t4_params.copy()
        lgbm_params['num_class'] = 3

        # prepare data for lgbm
        dset = lgbm.Dataset(x, y, silent = True)

        # perform cross-validation
        cv_results = lgbm.cv(lgbm_params, dset, num_boost_round=10000, 
                     nfold=5, stratified=False, shuffle=True, 
                     metrics='multi_logloss', early_stopping_rounds=100, 
                     verbose_eval=50, show_stdv=True, seed=0)
```

Comment: I guess you have solved this by now but it seems to suggest that you have target labels other than 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: I just realized this is because I somehow imported the wrong y value... Sorry about that!